# socket.io not able to emit to all the connected clients

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

used the socket.io-fiddle https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-fiddle and tried sending the io.emit continuously in every 10s. But my connected client is still not received any message.

main issue is not able to send the emit message to everyone in the socket connect list.

Also observed that not able to send message to room as well. Room seems to be always empty set.

code used:

```js
import { default as express } from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: true,
        methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
        allowedHeaders: ['pythonusername', 'pythonpassword', 'authorization'],
        credentials: true,
    },
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
    socket.on('join_chat_group', function (data) {
        console.log('event=join_chat_group');
        socket.join('chat1');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        console.log(`disconnect ${socket.id} due to ${reason}`);
    });
});

setTimeout(() => {
    io.emit('hello', 'name=sant=toallclients');
}, 1 * 1000);

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

ReactJS code looks like this

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const socket = io('ws://localhost:3001', {
    transportOptions: {
        polling: {
            extraHeaders: {
                pythonusername: 'ciR1QorvFx1U',
                pythonpassword: 'ENTzh1mrIeq',
            },
        },
    },
    transports: ['polling'],
});

function App() {
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(socket.connected);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            setIsConnected(true);
            socket.emit('join_python_discovery', 'react');
            socket.emit('join_chat_group', 'react');
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            setIsConnected(false);
        });
        socket.on('Start1234', function (data) {
            console.log(data, 'hello');
        });
        socket.on('hello', function (data) {
            console.log(data, 'hello');
        });
        // socket.on('pong', () => {
        //  setLastPong(new Date().toISOString());
        // });

        socket.emit('my message', `{name:'santhosh'}`);

        return () => {
            socket.off('connect');
            socket.off('disconnect');
            socket.off('hello');
            socket.off('Start1234');
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>UI</h1>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

something sill is only missed. can someone help me on this?

version:
*"socket.io": "^4.0.0"*

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-fiddle

**client.js**

```js
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});

socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
});

socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});

// add listening event
socket.on("test", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});

socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
  console.log(`disconnect due to ${reason}`);
});
```

**server.js**

```js
import { default as express } from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {});
 
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);

  // to send message to cliente
  socket.emit('test', {message: "hello"})

  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
    console.log(`disconnect ${socket.id} due to ${reason}`);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: I would like to send message to everyone connected to the socket server... is it available in the code what you shared?

Comment: Yes. Connected user can get the message from server.